# Error when get rss from a url?

Tags: php

I have a sample code:

```
<?php 
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load('http://www.haivl.com/rss');

$items = $doc->getElementsByTagName('item');
foreach ($items as $key => $item) {
    $titles = $item->getElementsByTagName( "title" );
    $title = $titles->item(0)->nodeValue;
    echo $title;
}
?>
```

I can't get title from this url, why error, can help me fix this error !

Comment: Well, what error are you getting?

Comment: @Pekka웃: error echo not data title

Comment: Check whether title are available in $items array? If it is available than then you need to check variable assigning part inside loop.

Comment: you trying to make echo on `$titles` which are dom elements !

Comment: can you show `$items` array code?

Comment: @All: I had check from link http://www.haivl.com/rss, data ok, but result can't get data

Answer (score 2):

The problem is these two lines

```
$title = $titles->item(0)->nodeValue;
echo $titles;
```

You're assigning the title value to `$title` but echoing `$titles`. `$titles` is a `DOMNodeList` and can't be converted to a string implicitly. You want to do

```
$title = $titles->item(0)->nodeValue;
echo $title;
```